# Sum of Two Squares in Ring Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Show that a prime $p$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is a sum of two squares iff -1 is a square in $\mathbb
{Z}_{p}$.  This example belong to my ring theory book didnt have ideal.
i read in number theory that 
If $p$ is a prime number of the form $4k+1$ then there exist positive integers $a$,$b$ such that $a^{2}+b^{2}=p$.
can we use this ?

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 4):

The first implication :
$$p=a^2+b^2 \implies (ab^{-1})^2\equiv -1 \mod p $$
The other implication: if $x^2\equiv -1 \mod p$  then $x$ has order $4$ in $\Bbb Z_p$ and hence $4$ divides $p-1$ i,e $p$ is of the form $p=4k+1$ and use the implication you have in the book